# Dropdown menu doesn't overlapping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My problem is in overlapping as you see from title.
My code is working, but when I put dropdown list into nav-bar container it doesn't drop down when I click on it.
Here is my code from view:

```
 <div class="navbar-inner">

     <div class="container">
  <%= link_to "Print- it- Green", root_path, id: "logo" %>

  <nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs custom">
      <li class="active"><%= link_to "Overview", '#'  %>           
      </li>

      <li><%= link_to "About",    '#' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "What we do", '#' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Partners", '#' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", '#' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Support", '#' %></li>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle"
             data-toggle="dropdown"
             href="#">
        <%#= current_user.email %>
            <b class="caret"></b>dfghdfdfh
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "add website", new_website_path %></li>
            <li><%#= link_to "account settings", edit_registration_path %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </ul>
  </nav>   
</div>
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the dropdown.js file in the header and initialize it? That is a common problem I have seen around.

Comment: I thaught, that <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> will include all javascript files. I will try what you are talking about, but it is working outside nav bar .